# Restrict Fast Forward iPhone video.js

Tags: video.js

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to restrict fast forwarding for videos playing in an iPhone. Does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't. iOS doesn't allow customisation of controls in full screen playback, and playback is always full screen on iPhone.

Comment: Whenever I visit our local news station's website and view a video, it requires me to watch an ad before the video will play. I've tried to scroll to the end of the ad (on my iPhone), however it reverts back to where it was before I tried to fast forward. I can't figure out how they were able to accomplish this.

Comment: Perhaps there's something you could do with keeping track of the position and seeking back when the user seeks, but that seems messy.